# Is this a bug about precedence group in swift?

Tags: swift, operator-precedence

I found an intriguing or confused problem about custom defined precedence group in swift.

This is Swift 5.0.1 with Xcode 10.2.1 under macOS Mojave 10.14.5

```swift
precedencegroup PowerPrecedence {
    lowerThan: BitwiseShiftPrecedence
    higherThan: AdditionPrecedence
    associativity: right
}
infix operator ^^ : PowerPrecedence

extension Int {
    static func ^^ (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {
        var result = 1
        for _ in 1...rhs { result *= lhs }
        return result
    }
}
print(3 ^^ 2 * 3)
print(2 ^^ 2 ^^ 2 * 2)
```

I set the precedence of PowerPrecedence that cannot be compared with MultiplicationPrecedence deliberately.

The line "print(3 ^^ 2 * 3)" incurs compiler's complain:
"Adjacent operators are in unordered precedence groups 'PowerPrecedence' and 'MultiplicationPrecedence'"
and that is what I expected.

But if I comment this line, the next line "print(2 ^^ 2 ^^ 2 * 2)" outputs 32. Shouldn’t this line incur the same error as the previous line? Is this a bug in Swift?

If I change "associativity" to "left" in the definition of PowerPrecedence, both lines indicate "Adjacent operators are in unordered precedence groups..." error.

Comment: I feel like this is a bug as well. When I change the number literals to `f(2)`, `f(3)`, `f(4)` etc, where `f` just prints the parameter and returns it, just to see in which order the expression is evaluated, Swift exited with code -1...

Comment: Filed a bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10970